# Migration options showing only meta.graphicdesign.com

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, migration, flagging

After I tried to flag one question (although in the end it is not necessary), I get on the following screen in the flag popup:

[image]

The only option I see in `Flagging -> Closing -> Off-Topic -> Migration` is to migrate to `meta.graphicdesign.strackexchange.com`

Is this supposed to be like this or am I missing some options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is the intended behavior. Once we graduate, then we can choose which sites to list as possible migration paths.

For now, you can flag it for moderator attention and specify which site you think it should be sent to. The general rule is "[never migrate crap"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986/216955), so I'll usually confer with the moderators of the destination site to see if it's a suitable question for their site.